# How to get the value of an textField by its name and tag - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

i got a view where the user is can input a name and an age : [image: screenshot]
the fields got the following names and the tag-value 1.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *amount;
```

If the user creates more textFields, they will be also named *name und *age and linked to the ViewController. The value will be counted to 2 for the second pair of Fields, 3 for the third pair etc.

I want to foreach an array which is as long as the number of textField pairs and count i++;
How do is the syntax for getting the values referring to name and tag? I googled and found the following solution which works if the tags are unique, which is not the case in my situation. How do I extend this selection by the elements name?

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
NSString *amount1 = textField.text;
```

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. If you're creating them programmatically, you won't want them to be `IBOutlet`s. You probably want to keep an `NSArray` that has `UITextField` objects in it. Also, if you're using the actual phrase "Add Row" that should maybe give you a clue that it would be a good idea to use a `UITableView`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Table Row looks not the way I want it to look... Another problem is the absolute positioning of elements. I do not know on which coordinates I have to create the additional textFields. Do I really have to calculate a new position every time i generate another "row" for the two buttons below my textFields?

Comment: I would look into customizing a `UITableView`. There are many ways to adjust the way it looks. If you add elements without a table, you're going to have to keep track of the location of the last row, move your button elements down on each row generation, and put it all in a scroll view... so you're basically getting a dumbed-down custom `UITableView` without the benefits of the built-in functionality of a `UITableView`

Comment: How would the solution with an NSMutable Array of UITextFields look? I have no idea how I could realize that :/ Currently I got an Person Class, that is able to create a new empty object with a slot for amount and name, which then gets appended to my NSMutable Array. When every value is filled in and the user clicks the complete button, the objects will be filled by the textField Values.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving this all into a `UITableView`. There are many ways to modify the way it looks by using custom `UITableViewCell`s and adjusting the table's background color, separator insets, etc.

Look around for a tutorial that you like for creating a custom cell, and give it your 2 `UITextField`s as `@property` variables. Create a new `UITableViewController` instead of your existing controller and `#import` your custom cell class.

**TableViewController.h**

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *namesArray;
    NSMutableArray *amountsArray;
    UITextField *activeField;
}
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
// only relevant code displayed
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [namesArray count] + 1;  // extra row for the "Add Row" row
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIButton *addDataButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [addDataButton setTitle:@"Add Data to Array"];
    [addDataButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addDataToArray) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // customize your button as needed

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footerView = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    [footerView addSubview:addDataButton];
    return footerView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == [namesArray count]) // the last row
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@""];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Row";
        return cell;
    }

    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"YourReuseID";  // use whatever you set in your custom cell class
    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameField.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameField.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.nameField.delegate = self;
    cell.amountField.text = [amountsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.amountField.tag = indexPath.row + 1000000; // to make sure it doesn't have the same tag as your nameField
    cell.amountField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if(indexPath.row = [namesArray count])
    {
        [namesArray addObject:@""];
        [amountsArray addObject:@""];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeTextField = textField;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.tag < 1000000)
    {
        [namesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
    }
    else
    {
        [amountsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag - 1000000 withObject:textField.text];
    }
}

- (void)addDataToArray
{
    [activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
    // add your data as needed. The first row's name/amount will be available in [namesArray objectAtIndex:0] and [amountsArray objectAtIndex:0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag with value: 1000 + i pour name and 2000 + j pour amount.

Then, to get value of name associated, use tag = tagOfName + 1000.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How does that would look in code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a logic which uniquely identifies textfields.

Set the tags of name and amount as mentioned below.

Tag of the name textfield for nth row should be (n * 2) + 1 where n=0,1,2.....n-1

Tag of the amount textfield for nth row should be (n * 2) + 2 where n=0,1,2.....n-1

You can get the value associated with textfield by using the below statements

```
UITextField *nameNTextField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:(n * 2) + 1]; //where n=0,1,2.....n-1
NSString *nameN = nameTextField.text;

UITextField *amountNTextField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:(n * 2) + 2]; //where n=0,1,2.....n-1
NSString *amountN = nameTextField.text;
```